# On Ansible, how do I use different postgresql.conf files depending on the host/service?

Tags: postgresql, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am running two different servers, each has a different use case for `postgres`, therefore I would like to have each `postgres` service run on a different configuration (defined in `postgresql.conf`).

The current ansible setup is as follows for postgresql, where postgresql is a `role`:

```
postgresql
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
└── templates
    ├── pg_hba.conf
    └── postgresql.conf
```

My objective is to understand what is the best practice for doing this, without having to give different names to the `postgresql.conf` files (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define what file need to be used in the inventory, this way:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    postgress:
      hosts:
        host1:
          postgress_conf: postgresql.conf
        host2:
          postgress_conf: pg_hba.conf
```

Then use the variable in the playbook [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) task:

```yaml
- hosts: postgress

  tasks:
    - copy:
        src: templates/{{ postgress_conf }}
        dest: /etc/postgresql/x.x/main/postgresql.conf
```